# How to place text between two html tags in C#

Tags: c#, html, string, tags, richtextbox

I am making a simple `HTML` editor in `C#`.

I have a `boldText` button which adds a `<b> </b>` html tag in `textArea` RichTextBox. My goal is to type a word in a `textArea`, select it and press that `boldText`button to paste the word between bold tags.

For example : `<b> Word </b>`. Just like here, in the editor, when you post your question. Hope I explained my problem clear enough. Here is my code for that button:

```
private void boldText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textArea.SelectionLength = 0;
    textArea.SelectedText = "<b> </b>";
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, maybe you are trying to do this

```
private void boldText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textArea.SelectedText = string.Format("<b>{0}</b>", textArea.SelectedText); 
    textArea.SelectionLength = 0;
}
```